# what is the differnce between coinitialize and coinitializeex?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

```
coinitialize(Null);
    {
        _In_opt_ LPVOID pvReserved, //parameters
        _In_     DWORD  dwCoIn
Coinitializeex(Null);
    {
       _In_opt_ LPVOID pvReserved,
       _In_     DWORD  dwCoInit
    }
```

Can you explain briefly?

Comment: The difference is clearly explained in the documentation. [`CoInitialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543.aspx) does not have a `dwCoInit` parameter, it initializes the calling thread to `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` only. Whereas [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx) lets you choose the desired initialization options.

Comment: can use the two functions at same file or program.what my proplem is they calling coinitialize(NULL).after that they are calling coinitializeex(NULL,Coinit_multithreaded).that second one is getting exited with code 0.the error is cant set the mode after it is set.if i commanded the coinitialize(null) it is working fine.can you assist me.might be what is the proplrm

Comment: win32com tag is wrong here, because it is used for questions about a Python module.

Comment: @PandyaChinna again, read the documentation, this is covered in detail. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 10):

Calling

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
```

is equivalent to calling

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
```

So if your application first calls `CoInitialize(NULL)` and later (in the same thread) `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)`, this would be equivalent to

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543.aspx) states

> Typically, the COM library is initialized on a thread only once. Subsequent calls to CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx on the same thread will succeed, as long as they do not attempt to change the concurrency model, but will return S_FALSE.

In your case you are trying to change the concurrency model, so the call will fail.

If COM was not used before the call to `CoInitializeEx()`, and you cannot remove the previous call to `CoInitialize()`, you could try to put a call to `CoUninitialize()` between the two.

Note also that the COM initialization is per thread, so maybe another workaround would be possible using different threads.

If you can change the call to `CoInitialize()`, simply replace it with

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
```